# Java getting files with referenced name

Tags: java, sql, image, file

I have a folder where images are stored for films with the same name as the film now when the user searches, the respective Image should show up for that film.

```
File ImageDisplay = new File("src/icons/random.png");  
BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(ImageDisplay);
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(originalImage);
```

Now if i run this everything works fine and that image appear on every film.

But i want to do something like this:

```
File ImageDisplay = new File("src/icons/"+MOVIE_TITLE+".png");  
BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(ImageDisplay);
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(originalImage);
```

Where MOVIE_TITLE is the film name from the database. But this gives me error which i cant seem to understand why. if i remove everything and just print it out by using:

```
System.out.println("src/icons/"+MOVIE_TITLE+".png");
```

The output in the console is correct for every movie where it prints out for example: The Godfather.png and so on. What am i missing?

Comment: What error do you get? Can you post your code in the form of an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)?

Comment: Is it just when the movie title has spaces?

Comment: If you are using Eclipse, you may need to refresh your project to make it aware of new files you've added.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. The error was that all films didn't have images and when it couldnt find that image for a corresponding film it gave an error.

I solved the problem by checking if the file exists first with this code:

```
 if(ImageDisplay.exists()) { 
             ImageDisplay = new File("src/icons/"+titleString+".png"); 
            } else {
                ImageDisplay = new File("src/icons/SsSs.png");
            }
```

And if the image doesn't exist replace it with another one.